# Laravel - How to add jQuery plugin to .vue view?

Tags: jquery, laravel, vue.js, webpack, plugins

I need to add jQuery plugin scrollify to my Vue.js view in Laravel project, how to do it?

I did import in master.blade.php

```
<script src="{{asset('js/libs/jquery.scrollify.js')}}"></script>
```

and now i want to use it in my vue.js homepage

```
import $ from 'jquery'
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            $(function() {
                $.scrollify({
                    section : ".section",
            });
        });
        },

        methods: {

        }
    }
</script>
```

It throws me error

```
Uncaught TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.scrollify is not a function
```

Is there some clean way to import jQuery plugins in Laravel project to use it in Vue.js? Thanks for advice!

Comment: Please never highjack scroll behavior.

Comment: @tauzN ok, but I still want to know how to import jQuery plugins in Laravel...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should install jquery and scrollify plugin as module via npm :

```
npm i jquery --save 
npm i jquery-scrollify --save
```

then import into your vue file :

```
import $ from 'jquery'

$.scrollify({
    section : ".example-classname",
});
```

and you dont need to put in

> $(function() {})

just put your code directly in mounted function:

```
  mounted() {
                $.scrollify({section : ".section",});
        }
```